# Score output based on multiple pandas dataframe columns

Tags: pandas

**What am I trying to do?**

I'm trying to generate a `total_score` column based on two other columns.

- The `level_count` column will have a min value of `1` and max of `3`
- The `range_bins` column will have a min value of `low` and max of `very_high`

In order to sum I created a temp `range_score` column from `1` to `4`.  Is there a better way than creating this temp column?

How do I normalise the scores so `level_count` and `range_bins` have the same weighting even though the range of each column differs? (3 values vs 4)

**Data**

```
data = { 'level_count': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1},
 'range_bins': {0: 'high', 1: 'medium', 2: 'low', 3: 'very_high'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["range_score"] = df.range_bins.replace({"low": 1, "medium": 2,"high":3,"very_high":4})

df["total_score"] = df[["level_count","range_score"]].sum(axis=1)
```

drop temp column and show output:

```
df.drop(columns= "range_score")

   level_count  range_bins  total_score
0   2           high        5
1   2           medium      4
2   3           low         4
3   1           very_high   5
```

**Desired output**

Rows 2 and 3 have equal importance and the `total_score` should reflect this.  I may also need to add other similar columns with maybe only two categories in a similar way.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve equal weighting of row 2 and 3, you could create a function that takes a row from the dataframe and then write down the entire logic. You can then apply this function to the dataframe with `df.apply`. Since I cannot tell the complete logic from your description, I can only provide half the solution - You will have to write down the complete logic.

```
def total_score(row):
    if row.level_count == 1 & row.range_bins == 'very_high':
        return 4
    elif row.level_count == 2 & row.range_bins == 'very_high':
        return ?
    elif row.level_count == 2 & row.range_bins == 'very_high':
        return ?
    
df['total_score'] = df.apply(lambda x: total_score(x))
```

Comment: `Rows 2 and 3 have equal importance and the total_score should reflect this.`

Comment: See update. You will have to outline the logic more clearly, since it is hard to tell what 'very_high' should map to when the `level_count` column equals e.g. 2 instead of 1.
Anyways, you can achieve the desired result by creating a mapping function like the above one.